# How to use JSOUP in Android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to parse html-page with this code < span class = bld >1.2456 RON < / span > I want to get text "1.2456 RON" with SOUP in Android. What will I have done? Tell me please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173538/android-jsoup-example/5318771#5318771

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how you do it:

```
String html  = "< span class = bld >1.2456 RON < / span >";

Elements e = new Jsoup(html).select(".bld");

System.out.println(e.get(0).text().toString());
```