# parsing data from html page

Tags: android, html, parsing

I am developing an android project.i want to access some portion of a webpage but how can i do so? which parser suits the best for this task and also how to use this parser.
i use the following method to access the webpage but now want to parse this page

```
public void call_a_site()
    {   
            try
        {      
            Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.dsebd.org/" );
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));

        }

    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

plz help..
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173538/android-jsoup-example might answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the JSoup cookbook.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

This has a lot of good information in it and should be able to answer most of your questions.

You are probably looking for something along the lines of this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup library is the best option for Html parse.

Step 1: Download jsoup.x.x.x.jar [download link](http://jsoup.org/download) 
Step 2: Import in libs folder in IDE
Step 3: Set as library

Sample

```
        // Connect to the web site
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        // Using Elements to get the Meta data
        Elements description = document
                    .select("meta[name=description]");
        //Locate the content attribute
            desc = description.attr("content");
```