# Download using jsoup into android table

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I'm quite new to this both submitting a question and new with Android.

I'm trying to download a ul from a website using jsoup to a listview. Not sure how to do it to be honest wondering is someone can help me.

The website displays a list of phone names and I'd like to download it into an android table.

I'm not sure what more information you might need to help me solve this.

Comment: Can you post the url or a sample of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but take a look at the Jsoup selector page:

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

Also, this other answered topic might be able to help you:

[Android JSoup Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173538/android-jsoup-example)

EDIT:
You can probably connect to, and get the data from, the website using jsoup. Use a loop to make sure you're getting each phone name that you want, add it to a string array, then use this

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, PHONENAMEARRAY));
```

to attach your data to your list view. Good luck!