# parsing an image url from an html file

Tags: java, android, html, image, parsing

I want to search through a html file and then get the url to an image on that page. This url should then be saved as a string - thats all. The problem is I really don t know how to start.

My app of course knows the url to the page where the image is located.
As an example lets take this url:

---

On this page I need the url of the big image as string. When I view the sourcecode I can locate the url but I dont know how to code that - this is the url I need:

---

(the text within the quotation marks only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment). It's a HTML parser that will allow you to access DOM elements using css selectors (like jQuery).

```
// Parse your HTML:
// 1. From string:
Document doc = JSoup.parse(htmlAsString);

// 2. Or from an URL:
Document doc = JSoup.connect("http://my.awesome.site.com/").get();

// Then select images inside it:
Elements images = doc.select("img");

// Then iterate
for (Element el : images) {
    String imageUrl = el.attr("src");

    // TODO: Do something with the URL
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) HTML parser. There is a relevant answer on SO that explains the basic usage of jsoup - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318771/1321873

Answer (score 0):

Okay this did the job :) I am getting the image url now:

```
public class jSoupEx {

    private static final String elements = null;

    public static void main(String args[]){


        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://***/index.php/Datei:***.jpg").get();
            Element image = doc.select("img").first();
            String url = image.absUrl("src");
            System.out.println(url);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}