# Image with text with in bullet point

Tags: android, android-view

first of all wish you

#### Very Happy New Year.

Now come to the point. Here i want to show text with icon. I am only able to show the text but not the icon.How can i do this?

#### one important thing i am Getting response from server. Images can be changed. Whole thing is coming in shot.Not line by line

#### Below is the sample :

[image]

Any kind of  help will be extremely appreciated.

#### Updated:

Response from server:

```
<div class=\"specsSection\">\n<p><strong>Entertainment on the Go</strong></p>\n
<table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"tblSpecs\"><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/dolbyplus.jpg\" />
</td>\n<td>Sharp and Natural Sound with Digital Dolby Plus</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/wifi.jpg\" /></td>\n<td>
GPRS + WiFi (With Voice Calling)</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/lcd.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>7\"Capacitive Touch LCD</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/dualcore.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>Dual Core Processor</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/storage.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>1 GB RAM, 4 GB eMMC</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/android.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>Andorid 4.2 JellyBean</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/battery.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>7+ hours of battery life</td>\n</tr></table></div>\n<div style=\"clear:both\">      </div>\n",
```

Comment: then use one `ImageView` and one `TextView` in same layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `android:drawableLeft=""` attribute for `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image1" />
```

and if you want to give the space between image and text use,

```
 android:drawablePadding="" attribute...
```

and to set images dynamically, use

[textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

so you are getting image Urls from Server. see the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210700/best-method-to-download-image-from-url-in-android) how to download images from Server. get the Stream from Connection and decode it using [BitmapFactory.decodeStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);
```

use AsyncTask to download the image and get the Bitmap, set to TextView in UI thread...

Comment: please check the updated question.Here some confusion has got created.

Comment: But response is in HTML tag so again how can i get the images and text separately. as you can see the above, i have posted my response.

Comment: again My question is how i filter the image tag and text separtely  while i am getting this in Single string.@Gopal rao

Comment: @rup35h see the thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480130/parsing-html-in-java-for-an-android-app and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998163/android-java-get-html-image-tag-from-string and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010171/parsing-an-image-url-from-an-html-file

and see some sample code here https://gist.github.com/Antarix/4167655

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image_at_left"` in order to assign image exactly at the left of the `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image_at_left"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

---

**OR**

You can set the drawables programmatically..

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds();
```

[Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: can'Name can't be displayed i am getting response with html tag should i remove the tags??or you want me to paste the response here??

Comment: What do you mean by **hatm** tag??

Comment: means you need to change the **drawableLeft** programmatically ??